# JS working in Chrome but not Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

The following code gives a simple sign up form and uses JavaScript to validate the user's input. When run in chrome, there are alerts as expected. But in IE and Firefox, the page only goes to adduser.php without alerts even nothing has been entered into the form.

**CSS**

```
.signup {
    font: normal 14px helvetica;
    color: #000000;
    border: solid 6px #555555;
    }
```

**JS**

```
function validate() {
    var fail = "";
    fail += validateForename(document.getElementById("forename").value);
    fail += validateSurname(document.getElementById("surname").value);
    fail += validateUsername(document.getElementById("username").value);
    fail += validatePassword(document.getElementById("password").value);
    fail += validateAge(document.getElementById("age").value);
    fail += validateEmail(document.getElementById("email").value);

    if (fail == "") return true;
    else alert(fail);
    return false;
}


function validateForename(str) {
    if (str == "") return "No forename has been found\n";
    return "";
}

function validateSurname(str) {
    if (str == "") return "No surname has benn found\n";
    return "";
}

function validateUsername(str) {
    if (str == "") return "No username has been found\n";
    if (str.length < 5) return "Username must be at least 5 characters\n";
    if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/.test(str)) return "Only a-z, A-Z, 0-9, - and _ are allowed in username\n";
    return "";
}

function validatePassword(str) {
    if (str == "") return "Password can not be empty\n";
    if (str.length < 6) return "Password must be at least 6 characters\n";
    if (!/[0-9]/.test(str) || !/[a-z]/.test(str) || !/[A-Z]/.test(str)) return "Password must have at least one each of a-z, A-Z, 0-9\n";
    return "";
}

function validateAge(str) {
    if (isNaN(str)) return "No age has been found\n";
    if (str < 18 || str > 110) return "Age must be between 18 and 110\n";
    return "";
}

function validateEmail(str) {
    if (str == "") return "No email address has been found\n";
    if (!(str.indexOf('.') > 0 && str.indexOf('@') > 0) || /[^a-zA-Z0-9_-.@]/.test(str)) return "The email address is invalid\n";
    return "";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="signup" border="0" cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <th colspan="2" align="center">Sign Up</th>
    <form method="post" action="adduser.php" onSubmit="return validate()">
        <tr>
            <td>Forname:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" maxlength="32" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Surname:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" maxlength="32" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="16" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="12" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="age" id="age" maxlength="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="64" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Signup" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: By the way, your HTML is a little malformed. Your `<th>` cell is not enclosed in a `<tr>`, and your `<form>` declaration is also in a strange place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line (55):

```
if (!(str.indexOf('.') > 0 && str.indexOf('@') > 0) || /[^a-zA-Z0-9_-.@]/.test(str)) return "The email address is invalid\n";
```

The character class you declared is invalid:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-.@]/  //--> Wrong
/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.@-]/  //--> Right
```

The browser tries to interpret `_-.` as a range of characters between `_` and `.`, and sorely fails.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex (line 55) produces an error in Firebug (SyntaxError: invalid range in character class) :

> /[^a-zA-Z0-9_-.@]/

Try this one instead :

> /[^\w-]+/gi

Works for me now in FF and IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression object is not very reliable:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-.@]/
```

Chrome tolerates that, but Firefox doesn't understand that `_-.` is not a character range, like `a-z`. You can move `-` to the very end to avoid ambiguity. Final regexp becomes (`i` means case insensitive match)

```
/[^a-z0-9_.@-]/i
```